# How to get intellisense working in vscode while python code located in different modules

Tags: python-3.x, oop, visual-studio-code, module, pylance

I've just started experimenting with python. I have vscode with pylance being the default language server. Before pylance I another MS python language server. Didn't make any difference. I'm on windows but virtual env located in WSL2 (Ubuntu) just in case it makes difference.

I started experimenting with pysnow and when the code and functions located in one file, suggestions work great for functions and what is included in pysnow itself, I believe it is called an annotation. (as docstrings?). See examples below:

suggestion for available functions

[image: suggestion for available functions]

pysnow annotation

[image: pysnow annotation]

However, when I started to split functions into different modules I can no longer see those suggestions any longer...

I do imports in the beginning and according to pylance, modules resolved correctly as it is suggested function name from another module when I start typing it. However, there are no suggestions like I posted on the screenshots above.

I do believe it is possible somehow to bring them back and hopefully the community can help me out :)

Thanks!